# Given two points in a 2D space, find the transformation

Tags: python, transformation

I'm looking for pointers on the below problem statement:

- Given two points in 2D space how do we find the transformation ( linear, rotation, reflection or affine )

I've seen a lot of posts in both stack overflow and math stack overflow. None of them gave me the answer I was looking for. I also looked at WIKI link, but it was not very specific.

Also, I'm not looking to reuse any existing libraries. I want to write it bare bones to learn how this happens.

I will be using Python.

Comment: On a side note, you can't do this with two points.  You need three to have an unambiguous transformation in 2D space.

Comment: All I'm looking to do is find the transformation given two images. The first idea I had was to split them into pixels and compare the transformation of the pixels. Does that even work that way?

Comment: Well, the hard part with that is finding the same points in both images.  I'm writing up an answer for the case where you know exactly which points are which, but it leaves out the harder problem of matching which points are which (search for "scale invariant feature transform").